# Angular 6: Property 'of' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'

Tags: rxjs, angular6, rxjs6

I am using **Angular 6** 
using **"rxjs": "^6.0.0",**

**ERROR** : Property 'of' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { Observable, Subject, pipe, of } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable()
export class MiTranslateLoaderService implements TranslateLoader {

  getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.of({
      lbl_select: 'Select',
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since RxJS 6 the correct and recommended way of using `of()` (RxJS 5 in `Observable.of()`) is this:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
```

I think this `import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';` will work only while you have `rxjs-compat` package installed.

Comment: It's important to note that you must change "return Observable.of" to just "return of"

Answer (score 9):

**There are some updates in rxjs: ( Its rxjs6)**

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
```

It will work only when your app has **`rxjs-compat`**  package installed

You can import `of` from `rxjs`:

`import { Observable,of } from 'rxjs';`

And simply return **`of()`**

```
 return of({
      lbl_select: 'Select',
    });
```

So your code will be:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable()
export class MiTranslateLoaderService implements TranslateLoader {

  getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<any> {
    return of({
      lbl_select: 'Select',
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is working for me.

Angular CLI 6.0.8

RxJS 6.2.2

```
import {of} from 'rxjs/index';


this.dataService.currentData

    .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
    .pipe(switchMap((myData:MyDataType) =>
      of(this.anotherService.get(myData._id))))
    .pipe(map((response) => {
         if(response instanceof Error) {
            console.log('error:');
            console.dir(response);
         }
         return response;
    }))
    .subscribe((data:any) => {
       doStuff(data);
      },
      response => {
        console.log('response error');
        console.log(response)
      },
      () => {
        console.log('response complete.');


      });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to import `of` from `rxjs/observable/of`

```
import { of } from "rxjs/observable/of";
```

Usage:

```
return of({
  lbl_select: 'Select',
});
```

Update: for **rxjs version 6** without rxjs-compat, you need to import `of` from `rxjs` itself as mentioned by @martin.

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
```

[Migration guide to rxjs6](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md)

Answer (score 1):

With the release of version 6, **RxJS** changed its internal package structure

https://www.academind.com/learn/javascript/rxjs-6-what-changed/#import-statement-update-path

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
// or 
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to return of(..) directly :

```
getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<any> {
    return of({
      lbl_select: 'Select',
    });
```